# gdb - assign pipe output to a variable

Tags: gdb, pipe

I have the following command , I would like to assign his output to a variable:

```
(gdb) pipe monitor get info | grep cross2_Release.nss | cut -c 3-13
0x566f80400
```

Tried this

```
set $main = 'pipe monitor get info | grep cross2_Release.nss | cut -c 3-14'
```

> No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.

Expected result would be to have $main equals to `0x566f80400`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I thought this would work:

```
python output = gdb.execute('pipe monitor get info | grep cross2_Release.nss | cut -c 3-13', to_string=True)
python gdb.set_convenience_variable('main', gdb.parse_and_eval(output))
```

But this fails because the `pipe` command sends output to GDB's stdout rather than to a stream that `gdb.execute` can capture and put into a string. So here's something a little more crude:

```
shell printf 'set $main = ' > ~/.gdbtmp
pipe monitor get info | grep cross2_Release.nss | cut -c 3-13 >> ~/.gdbtmp
source ~/.gdbtmp
```

Comment: I ended up finding something similar to your solution, i think it's the same but mine it's more messed up.
`pipe monitor get info | grep cross2_Release.nss | cut -c 3-14 > gdb.tmp`
`shell echo -n 'set $main = ' | cat - gdb.tmp > temp && mv temp gdb.tmp`
`source ./gdb.tmp`
`shell rm ./gdb.tmp`

Answer (score 1):

Using the python [subprocess.check_output()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) function it's relatively simple to do that:

```py
py gdb.set_convenience_variable('main', gdb.parse_and_eval(subprocess.check_output('grep cross2_Release.nss | cut -c 3-13', shell=True, input=gdb.execute('monitor get info', to_string=True), text=True)))
```

But that's a lot to type, so I would pack that into a gdb convenience function:

```py
import subprocess

class Pipe(gdb.Function):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Pipe, self).__init__("pipe")

    def invoke(self, gdb_cmd, pipe_cmd):
        return gdb.parse_and_eval(subprocess.check_output(pipe_cmd.string(), shell=True, input=gdb.execute(gdb_cmd.string(), to_string=True), text=True))

Pipe()
```

Which then could be used like this:

```py
set $main = $pipe("monitor get info", "grep cross2_Release.nss | cut -c 3-14")
```

Comment: Tried it, but unofrtunately my gdb does not support python scripting
`Python scripting is not supported in this copy of GDB`

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, gdb without python is only half the fun.